# geemap to tiff returns an empty array

Tags: tiff, geotiff, geemap

I have been having trouble using the GEEMAP Module. I have created a map in this module and have been trying to find a way to automate the download of maps using code. So far I have tried multiple things, including saving it as a GEOTIFF with .ee_export_image and .to_png, but they have not worked, and the GEOTIFF returned was empty. I was wondering if anybody had found a way to do this, or if anybody had made progress on this issue.

I tried the method .ee_export_image and saved it as tiff but then the map was empty. .to_png never really worked. All I need is to get the map exported as an image.